# UIWebView shows blank for some iOS 9 users (rare and strange)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView on a viewController, normally it loads a web page of my own website. But recently I found that UIWebView appears to be blank for a few users. Just a gray blank screen(I set it's backgroundColor to gray).

I'm using:

```
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.delegate = self;
webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
self.webView = webView;
```

and:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

I have come to known the following facts:

1. It's not a https url, and I have Allow Arbitrary Loads in Info.plist.
2. **Those users were able to see contents of that web page on that UIWebView before.** Then suddenly one day, without upgrading, reinstalling the app or the system, the UIWebView turns blank for them. I'm pretty sure it's the same url link.
3. Those users are able to access that specific link in their safari. And they are able to access urls with different hosts in my app.
4. If they manually kill the app and reopen it, it's still blank. **Even when they delete the app and reinstall it from the AppStore, it's still blank.**
5. Then after several days, without anything done particularly, the UIWebView returns to normal. The problem disappeared.
6. Once I was able to borrow a phone with that problem from a user. When I plug the phone in and ran debug from XCode, it immediately returns to normal.

This bug is driving me crazy for it's strange behavior, and it's really had to reproduce. Up to now I've got 4 reports of this bug, all of them are from iOS 9 users, no particular device. That problematic web page is powered by angularJS, if that helps.

I don't have any clue by now. Any suggestion would help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it was of the server side. Silly me.